# use lib file in delphi. how to import lib file

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

I got an API for a lib file.
With that lib file .h files were supplied. 
Now i want to call the lib file within the Delphi, and use its functionality.

how does the lib file get connected to the Delphi?

update: ok allot of work around is needed, what if i get a dll? how do i link that into the Delphi?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use a lib file to link to a DLL from Delphi. The .lib file would be used by C or C++ clients of the DLL.

In Delphi you need to manually translate the .h header file into a Pascal import unit using the `external` keyword. An example of this of the Windows.pas unit in the Delphi source. The fact that you can't use the .lib file is actually not a big issue because you have to translate the .h file no matter what.

Comment: This answer makes the assumption that a compiled DLL file is available for the associated LIB file.  It is in fact possible to compile something as EITHER a LIB file or a DLL file.  Where a DLL file is available, simply converting the associated header files (.H) is sufficient.  However, where the code has only been made available in a LIB file, completely converting the source to Delphi (if available) is required for it to be used within Delphi.  That said, it is unfortunate that Delphi has not supported .LIB while many other compilers have supported it for quite some time.

Comment: @glen to link to a static lib you can just link the lib into a dll with a C compiler

Comment: @David: Afaik the symbols won't be declared with export flags then, and thus not visible?

Comment: @marco you would need to re-export them with a .def file

Answer (score 0):

In certain cases it is possible to extract members of a .lib file using tools like the object file converter from Agner Fog (see http://www.agner.org/optimize/?e=0,34,36) to .obj files.

The syntax is

> objconv.exe libname.lib -lx

to extract all members.

By extracting all members you can ensure that there are no members missing. However, if there are further dependencies (to other .lib files) these won't be resolved and must be resolved manually.

Also translating the header files is still required.

Note: The object file format can also be converted. Delphi only understands OMF, while Intel compilers (for exampl) spit out only COFF. Thus a conversion is required, which can be done by the tool as well.

As said this only works in certain cases and it surely need some expertise in this area, because the compiler won't help much with error messages (often the messages are irritating and misleading).

Comment: "Delphi only understands OMF" - COFF .obj files can be linked since Delphi XE2, which was released in 2011.